# Bash script to delete files that do not match a certain date pattern

Tags: bash, file, date, cron, dayofweek

I have a project and I'm not sure the best way to handle it.

I have a Linux server that stores court recordings. I need to write a script that can be run via cron to automatically delete any recordings in a given folder that does NOT match the following pattern:

creation date is the second Monday, second Tuesday, fourth Monday, or Fourth Tuesday.

Whichever is the most recent pair (for example, since today is Thursday 7th August 2014, the only files that should be there would be for Monday 28th and Tuesday 29th of July) should stay; all other files should be deleted.

The file names use the following standard:

```
CourtroomName_CourtroomNumber_Date(YYMMDD)_Time(HHMMSS)_FileNumber.mp3
```

I saw similar questions, but they all dealt with just grabbing the newest via timestamp or some other agnostic means. I need something that will determine the actual day of the week, week number of the month, and determine based on that which files to keep and which to delete.

I can give any more information if necessary, just let me know.

Comment: `for i in $(find | grep -v **regex which matches second Monday** | grep -v **regex which matches second Thessay** | ....); do rm $i; done`

Such regexes can be written&debugged easily when You have access to real system

Comment: @Arenim: Your comment seems unfinished. regexes can be written and debugged easily if I have access to real system what? Root? Also, since I don't know regexes, I'd like to avoid finding a site to write them for me. Is there a way to do this using something similar to the SQL DATEPART() or the .NET Weekday() commands to determine this? I know enough bash to really get myself in trouble (I'm by no means fluent), so I thought I'd get some advice from here! Thanks!

Comment: @pmbasehore No he means when you can access your files. You don't need root. You can find plenty of tutorials to build your regex out there, like [this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). My 2 cents is that you should calculate beforehand the date of the 2nd monday, 2nd tuesday, ... and put it in `YYMMDD` format and use this values in your several grep

Comment: @Ploutox Ahh, thanks. Yes, I have access to the actual files in question.

Comment: I don't get the pattern, can you provide some examples ?

Comment: @Ploutox, I mean the pattern to keep/delete the files

Comment: An example filename:
_State_A_140807_105536_MZ001.mp3_
Note, I don't know what the "MZ001" means, but it's there in every file. It's irrelevant to this issue anyway.

Comment: @Sorin: This particular courtroom only holds sessions on the second and fourth Tuesday of the month. However, there are various preparations that occur on the second and fourth Monday of the month as well, so both Monday and Tuesday's are necessary. We need to remove any file _except_ for the most recent pair (either the fourth Monday/Tuesday or the second Monday/Tuesday). This may include files done on any other day of the week, which would be used for testing and not in any official capacity. Does that make more sense?

Comment: What happened in, for example, April 2014, where the fourth Monday was 2014-04-28, but the fourth Tuesday was 2014-04-22?  Actually, July 2014 also had the first fall on Tuesday, so the fourth Monday was 2014-07-28, but the fourth Tuesday was 2014-07-22.  Or is the rule really 'Fourth Monday and the day after that'?  Such rules are remarkably hard to express accurately.

Comment: And I guess a related question is what happens in, say, February 2011, where the fourth Monday is 28th February; is Tuesday 1st March used, or what?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I guess the best way to think of it is to use the second and fourth Tuesday, and the Monday immediately prior.

Comment: That makes sense.  Now to think about how to get the Nth W-day of a given month nicely...which was necessary anyway.  One good thing: the day before is always in the same month (for 2nd and 4th Tuesdays), so the Monday is simply the date one day before the Tuesday.  I've not yet found an incantation for GNU `date` (and the embedded `parse_datetime` library) that does the job I want, let alone the job you need done.  That likely means it will require multiple invocations of whatever code is used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's what I was afraid of. I figured accessing the filesystem would be easier in bash, but if it'll be easier to perform the logic in another language, I'm open...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
courtcheck() {
  local d=${1#*_}; d=${d#*_}; d=${d%_*}; d=${d%_*}
  local w=$(date -d"$d" +"%w")
  local n=$(((${d#????} - 1) / 7))
  #echo "$w, $n"
  [[ ($w == 1 || $w == 2) && ($n == 1 || $n == 3) ]]
  return $?
}

name="State_A_140807_105536_MZ001.mp3"
courtcheck "$name" && echo "$name"
name="State_A_140812_105536_MZ001.mp3"
courtcheck "$name" && echo "$name"
```